# how to get an XML file from a website using python?

Tags: python, regex, xml, api, pycharm

using 'bottle' library, I have to create my own API based on this website  http://dblp.uni-trier.de so I have to get data for each author. For this reason I am using the following link format http://dblp.uni-trier.de/pers/xx/'first letter of the last name'/'lastnamefirstname'.xml

Could you help me get the XML format to be able to parse it and get the information I need. 
thank you

```
import bottle
import requests
import re

r = requests.get("https://dblp.uni-trier.de/")

  #the format of my request is 
  #http://localhost:8080/lastname firstname

@bottle.route('/info/<name>')
def info(name):

    first_letter = name[:1]

    #mettre au format Lastname:Firstname
    ...

    data = requests.get("http://dblp.uni-trier.de/pers/xx/" + first_letter     + "/" + family_name + ".xml")

    return data

bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: What is the problem here? Getting the xml from the response or parsing the xml?

Comment: its getting the xml from the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import requests

url = 'some url'
response = requests.get(url)
xml_root = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)
```

> **fromstring** Parses an XML section from a string constant. This function can be used to embed “XML literals” in Python code. text is a
>   string containing XML data. parser is an optional parser instance. If
>   not given, the standard XMLParser parser is used. Returns an Element
>   instance.
>
> HOW TO Load XML from a string into an ElementTree
>
> ```
> from xml.etree import ElementTree
> root = ElementTree.fromstring("<root><a>1</a></root>")
> ElementTree.dump(root)
> OUTPUT
> <root><a>1</a></root>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The object returned from `requests.get` is not the raw data. You need to use text property to get the contents

[Response Content](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) Documentation

Note that:

- `response.text` returns content as unicode
- `response.content` returns content as bytes

Comment: I used print(data.text) and it returned the xml file I was looking for. now I can parse it. Thank you